# How to write a query to select only groups where certain values are present in all rows?

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions

I need to write a query for Oracle 11g to select only the groups which are highlighted in the image here.  Specifically, there are 3 columns -- A, B, and C.  Group 1 contains a null value in column C, group 2 contains several nulls in column C.Group 3 does not contain any null values in column C.  Group 4 yes contains some null values in column C, and Group 5 does NOT contain any null values in column C.

[image]

I need to selects only the groups of rows that do NOT contain any null values in column C -- that would be group 3 rows and group 5 rows.  I only need the group number, like return only a 3 and a 5  What SQL functions can I use to write this query?  What does this query look like?

something like (pseudo code)

```
select colA, count(*) As cnt From tblX join to itself on something
Where ...something ... 
Group By colA
```

(or we could skip the grouping and just select 3 and 5 or the three 3's and the three 5's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate function `COUNT(colname)` would only count non-NULL values, so something like this might work:

```
select A from yourtable
group by A
having count(A) = count(C)
```

assuming `A` is never NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a not in clause and subquery

```
select colA, count(*) As cnt 
From tblX 
Where colA not in (select distinct colA from tblx where colC is  null)
Group By colA
```